# Optimize Redirect 301 for a multilingual site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How to optimize Redirect 301 in .htaccess, not to write 3 times for different languages! Thank you! ( [.] = . )

```
Redirect 301 /ru/category/1269-name-tovar.html https://site[.]com/category
Redirect 301 /en/category/1269-name-tovar.html https://site[.]com/category
Redirect 301 /uk/category/1269-name-tovar.html https://site[.]com/category
```

Comment: do you want /uk/category/1269-name-tovar.html  to go site.com/category or site.com/category/1269-name-tovar.html   ?

Comment: /uk/category/1269-name-tovar.html

Answer (score 0):

This rewrite rule would 301 redirect `[any of your three languages]/category/*` to `https://example.com/category`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(ru|en|uk)/category/.+ https://example.com/category [L,R=301]
```

Comment: how can you then url (1269-name-tovar.html) ? A redirect will be for all category goods in another category?