# Laravel 5.4 optimizing redirect 301

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, redirect

I am creating some permanent redirects in laravel 5.4 and I want to know if this is the best way to do it and how to optimize this code. I saw in this answer [Optimize Redirect 301 for a multilingual site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603737/optimize-redirect-301-for-a-multilingual-site) an example in .htaccess but how to do the same in routes? and what is better, do it in **routes** or in **.htaccess**?

I've put this in **routes**:

```
Route::get('es/nosotros/quienes/quienes.php', function(){ return Redirect::to('quienes', 301); });
Route::get('en/nosotros/quienes/quienes.php', function(){ return Redirect::to('quienes', 301); });
Route::get('pt/nosotros/quienes/quienes.php', function(){ return Redirect::to('quienes', 301); });
```

Another question is that I have to redirect about 5,000 urls. As a final result, I'm going to get a file with the 5,000 old urls and the 5,000 new urls. Do I also include it in the routes file? In the .htaccess? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using a placeholder?

```
Route::get('{lang}/nosotros/quienes/quienes.php', function ($language) {
    return Redirect::to('quienes', 301)->with('language', $language);
});
```

The difference between `routes` and `.htaccess` is speed: the second one will not pass information to the application and the redirect answer will be received directly from the webserver (Apache). Server will thanks you!

Comment: Thanks Simone! I'm going to see how to optimize with the .htaccess the 5,000 urls ...